# Connect a AppService to Virtual Machine

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

I got a problem to connect a AppService to Virtual Machine, the propouse is have a AppService and can consume a rest API host in a VM, but connection will be through local network.

The "virtual solution" was to connect a vNet on my app service and assign a subNet, when the app service send a ping through my app (NodeJs) the VM response is success, but when try to send request with VM hostname instead of ip, the response is 'ECONNREFUSED'.

And I try to send ping with appservice IP from VM and the request fails.

The question is, how can I to connect my app service to my VM through localnetwork using HOSTNAME?

Thanks.

Comment: Where is the VM located, Is it on-Prem ?

Comment: sorry the VM located on azure

Answer (score 0):

Based on the post ([#13927](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/13927)) on Github issue, you may customize your own DNS server for Azure App Service.

You may set `WEBSITE_DNS_SERVER` and `WEBSITE_ALT_DNS_SERVER` with your custom DNS server IP.